# Recovering a password for a Word 2007 document

Tags: microsoft-word, passwords

I have an old Word 2007 document that I don't remember the password for. I'm guessing a brute force attack is the way to go to get it open. Anyone know of any free tools I can use to do this?

Comment: This kind of defeats the purpose of password protection. How do we know you're *entitled* to see what's in the document?

Answer (score 2):

If the file is saved in *.docx format, I believe it uses strong encryption that you would need to dictionary or brute force attack.

A search on the internet will show many software companies.  I don't know of any free ones.  If you do a lot of searches you sell see two or three names pop-up over and over.  There are also online services, if you want to pay and trust them with the contents of your document.

I too learned the hard way and started using [Keepass](http://keepass.info/) not only for website passwords, but document passwords as well.  I know it won't help now, but maybe it will save you in the future.

Good luck.